# Regex to Mask all but Last Two Digits of a Number of Specific Length

Tags: java, regex

I have a string where I am trying to mask ONLY a 10-digit number except for its last two. Looking for its regex value in Java for it.

For all intent and purposes the string is "Godel1234567890Escher753951852456Bach7894561230" should get "GodelXXXXXXXX90Escher753951852456BachXXXXXXXX30".

So far my regex value is `str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\d{10}(?!\\d)", XXXXXXXX)`
This is able to get ONLY 10-digits, however I can't seem to find any way to exclude the last 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching 10 digits, match 8 and 2 digits, *capture* the 2 digits and insert the captured digits in the replacement value:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\d{8}(\\d{2})(?!\\d)", "XXXXXXXX$1")
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pr8PdZ/1) for demo.

Comment: That did it! Took me better part of my evening trying to complete this one. Much appreciated it!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a single regex.  You might need a more sophisticated appendReplacment mechanism like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D)\\d{8}(\\d{2})(\\D?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(aString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while(m.find())
{
  m.appendReplacement(sb,"$1XXXXXXXX$2$3");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: My bad.  The code here is correct, but from reviewing other answers, it obviously can be done within a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, that I think is simpler and more readable:

```
str.replaceAll ("(\\D|\\b)\\d{8}(\\d{2}(\\D|\\b))", "$1XXXXXXXX$2");
```

Look for either a non-digit or word boundary (in this case, just beginning and end of string) in the beginning and end of the pattern, and then 8 digits + 2 digits between them.

Save everything that matched, except for the 8 digits, and re-insert with back references.

I'm not sure how it compares to @Andreas response, though, in terms of performance.

With your input, it can actually be simplified to this:

```
y = x.replaceAll ("(\\D)\\d{8}(\\d{2}(\\D|\\b))", "$1XXXXXXXX$2");
```